# How to view all current networks around me

Tags: networking, network-manager, routing, tunnel

I have an Ubuntu Server hosted on a raspberry pi 4. There is no desktop on it, only a terminal. I am trying to figure out how I could view all possible networks around me I could connect to. Then, I’d want to get information about it (ip address) and possibly connect to it, just as I could on my phone or laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ifconfig -a` to find a list of Ethernet/Wifi devices on your system. Examples of adapter names might be `eth0`, `wlan0`, `wlp4s0`, etc.

You can run `sudo iwlist wlp4s0 scanning` to get a list of WiFi networks. You may have to run this repeatedly to get a complete list of networks.

You can only find IP information for a network once you connect to it and communicate with the DHCP server on the network, assuming there is one which is typical, or have some other out-of-band source of information, such as talking to the system administrator of the network.

As far as connecting to networks, you probably want to use tools such as `nmcli` (NetworkManager command-line interface), `iwconfig`, and/or `wpa_supplicant`. Details of using each of those are quite long, so probably topics for separate answers.

EDIT: On the Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, you can run `raspi-config` to configure WiFi. This provides a menu-based configuration system that shouldn't require much explanation, The following link has more details if you need to manually tweak any connection details that aren't exposed in the menus of that tool: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md